# C expression must be a modifiable l-value returning pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to assign a returned pointer from a function to another pointer. Why can't I? Simple example:

```
int * foo(int * x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int * x = NULL;
    int * y = NULL;
    foo(x) = y;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want `*foo(x) = 42;`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this for fun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *foo(int *x) {
    return x + rand() % 3;
}

int main(void) {
    int x[3] = {0};
    srand(time(0));
    *foo(x) = 42;
    printf("x is {%d, %d, %d}\n", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to assign a returned pointer from a function to another pointer. Why can't I?

Because functions return *values*, not objects.  Objects have storage which can contain and represent values.  Values themselves are are transient and immutable.  Even pointer values.  Your example is analogous to this:

```
double bar(void) {
    return 1.0;
}

int main() {
    double y = 0.0;
    bar() = y;
}
```

The return value of `bar()` is a value.  You cannot assign to it because it is not an object and has no associated storage.

You could do the reverse: assign the return value of `bar()` to variable `y`, like so: `y = bar()`.  That's fine because `y` designates an object (it is the identifier of a variable, the most common kind of object).  Expressions that designate objects are called "lvalues", because they can appear on the **l**eft side of assignment statements and can also be evaluated to yield **value**s.

Different types, including those with pointer nature, don't really factor in here.  Every complete type affords both lvalue and non-lvalue expressions of that type.

You can *dereference* valid pointer expressions, however, even those that are not themselves lvalues, and such expressions are lvalues.  Thus, this variation on your program would be accepted:

```
int *foo(int *x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int nums[2] = { 42, 7 };
    int *x = &nums[0];
    int *y = &nums[1];

    *foo(x) = *y;
}
```

The final assignment will set the object to which the return value of `foo()` points (`num[0]`) to the value to which `y` points (`num[1]`).  That is, after that assignment, array `nums` contains elements `{7, 7}`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function returning the pointer should be on right side of the `=` --> `y = foo(x)`.

Here is a not so simple example to deomnstrate that:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *foo(int *x)
{
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{   
    int *x=NULL;
    int *y=NULL;
    int a=9;

    x=&a;

    y=foo(x);
    printf("%d\n",*y);

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `9`

Comment: What if my foo() doesn't always return x?

Comment: @user1000 Read a C book first. You need to learn the basics. SO is not a teaching sevice

Comment: @user1000 What do you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

The l-value of assignment operator should be a variable and not a value. 
You can't use a function since the function returns a value(pass by value in C). So it should be

```
y = foo(x);
```